# If $A$ is a bounded operator on $c_0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(Ae_n)(m)|$ is bounded uniformly in $m$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The following is Exercise 7,section 1, chapter 6 of Conway's *A course in Functional Analysis*.

Let $A\in {\cal B}(c_0)$ (${\cal B}(c_0)$ is linear bounded operators on $c_0$) and for $n\geq 1$, define $e_n \in c_0$ by $e_n(m)=\delta_{nm}$. Put $\alpha_{nm}=(Ae_n)(m)$ for $n,m\geq 1$. Prove $M = \sup_m\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\alpha_{nm}|< \infty.$

I think if I put $(Ae_n)(m)= \frac {(-1)^n}{nm} $, then $A\in B(c_0)$ but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\frac {(-1)^n}{nm}|=\infty$ . Where is my mistake? Please help me.

Comment: No, your operator $A$ does not appear to be bounded. Defining it on $e_n$ is only the beginning; then it needs to be extended to all of $c_0$. Suggestion for the problem: Think of the adjoint operator $A^*:\ell^1\to\ell^1$. Suggestion for using the site: write descriptive titles. Compare what I wrote to what you had originally ("a counterexample").

Comment: I can not show $\sum_{n\geq 1}|\alpha_{mn}|<\infty. $ Please hint me.

Comment: Do you know what the adjoint operator is? If $A:X\to X$ is bounded, then $A^*:X^*\to X^*$ is defined by $A^*(\phi)=\phi\circ A$. Recall that the dual of $c_0$ is $\ell^1$. Calculate $\|A^*(e_m)\|$ and you should find that it is the sum you need to bound.

Comment: Thanks or your answers, but I was suggested to compute $A^*$ after computing $\sum |\alpha_{nm}|<\infty$ in this exercise, thus I think I have to show $\sum |\alpha_{nm}|<\infty$ without using adjoint operator.

Comment: I don't have the book with me, but this looks very strange. The fact that the norm of adjoint operator is the same as the norm of $A$ requires no computation, only Hahn-Banach for one of two directions. Anyway, copper.hat posted an answer that does not use the adjoint.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. I made a mistake that now I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $e_m^*$ be the $m$-th unit vector in $l_1$ (the dual of $c_0$).
Let $\|A\|$ be the operator norm of $A$.

I have omitted a few details, but the general idea is much the same as that involved in showing that the induced $\infty$ matrix norm is the maximum row sum.

Let $x_N = \sum_{n=0}^N {\overline{e_m^*(A e_n)} \over | \overline{e_m^*(A e_n)}|}e_n$, then we see that $\|x_N\| \le 1$,  hence
$\|Ax_N\| \le \|A\|$, and in particular, $|e_m^*(Ax_N)| \le \|A\|$.
However, since $e_m^*(Ax_N) = \sum_{n=0}^N  |{e_m^*(A e_n)} | $,
we see that $\sum_{n=0}^N  |{e_m^*(A e_n)} | \le \|A\|$.

Answer (score 1):

*Your 'counterexample'*: With $x_n := (-1)^ne_n$ we have $Ax_n = \frac 1n\cdot(\frac 1m)_m$. For $n \in \mathbb N$ let $y_N = \sum_{n=1}^N x_n$, then $y_N \in c_0$ with $\|y_n\| = 1$. Extending your $A$ linearly to the span of $\{e_n\mid n \in \def\N{\mathbb N}\N\}$, we have 
$$ Ay_n = \sum_{n=1}^N Ax_n = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac 1n \cdot \left(\frac 1m\right)_m $$
Hence, as $\|y_N\| = 1$, 
$$ \|A\| \ge \|Ay_n\|= \sum_{n=1}^N \left\|\left(\frac 1m\right)_m\right\| = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac 1n \to \infty $$
So $A$ is unbounded.

**Hint**. As 900-sit-ups suggested, consider $A^*\colon \ell^1 \to \ell^1$. For $e_m \in \ell^1$, we have 
$$ (A^*e_m)_n = (A^*e_m)(e_n) = e_m(Ae_n) = \alpha_{nm} $$
So $\|A^*e_m\| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\alpha_{nm}|$. As $A$ is bounded, $A^*$ is.